# Oracle error 01843 not a valid month while storing entity

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have some date fields in my hibernate entity class.
Now I am trying to save entity into Oracle database without giving any date fields.(all date fields are null).I get error 'not a valid month.) I don't understand why I get this error if don't store any date field?

Comment: Care to share some of your code?

Comment: Check whether you are passing it as empty string instead of null.

Comment: Also the full error message?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use some empty strings with variable length arguments instead of null values :

```
select to_date(null,'mm') as "null" 
  from dual  -- > returns NULL

select to_date('','mm') as "empty_str_length_zero" 
  from dual  -- > returns NULL

select to_date('  ','mm') as "empty_str_length_one" 
  from dual  -- > returns ORA-01843: not a valid month

select to_date('   ','mm') as "empty_str_length_two" 
  from dual  -- > returns ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

Comment: After spending sometime,I found the root cause/stupid mistake.Just posting answer to help someone who might face the same issue..

somebody from team had created a field as timestamp but I was passing string to that field. But the field is actually a string.Issue resolved after changing field type to string.

Thanks!!